# ¿Cómo separar cadenas que contienen una palabra específica y 3 palabras más además de ella en medio de ciertos símbolos utilizados como separadores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, string, regex

```py
import re

sentences_list = [
'hay que ((VERB correr)), ((VERB)saltar), ((VERB)volar) y ((VERB)caminar) para llegar a ese lugar',
'El árbol ((VERB grande)), las hojas ((VERB)son) doradas y ((VERB)son) secas, los juegos del parque ((VERB)estan) algo oxidados y ((VERB)es) peligroso subirse a ellos',
'El viento es ((VERB)cálido) y ((VERB)es)) rápido y ((VERB)sacude) las hojas de los arboles',
'Hay ((VERB)terminar) esto y eso, luego hay que ((VERB)limpiar) y ((VERB)llevar) esas cosas y Tom ((VERB)vendrá) por nosotras',
'María ((VERB)pasará) unos días aqui, hay que ((VERB)mover) sus cosas viejas de aqui, ya que sus cosméticos ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí.', 
'ya lo hemos ((VERB)estudiado) y ((VERB)analizado), tom ya se ((VERB)encargo) de lo demás']


aux_list = []
for i_input_text in sentences_list:
    #SEPARATE LISTS HERE

    aux_list.append(i_input_text)

#I update the original variable with the string with the separations already done
sentences_list = aux_list
print(sentences_list) #--> print output list
```

**¿Cómo se deben realizar estas separaciones siguiendo estos criterios?**

**Criterios de separación de cadenas que se deben aplicar:** En la lista llamada `sentences_list` hay 5 cadenas, usando estos símbolos separadores `,` , `;` , `.` , `(?:,|)\s* y (?:l[oa]s|la|[eé]l)` o `(?:,|)\s*y + 'una palabra que comienza con una palabra que comienza con una letra mayúscula ^[A-Z]'`

Separe las cadenas si contienen al menos un `((VERB)(?:\w+\s*)+)` y 3 palabras `((?:\w+))?` sin contar lo que está en `(( VERB)( ?:\w+\s*)+)`.

Por ejemplo:

- En este caso no tienes que dividir la cadena:

`'hay que ((VERB correr)), ((VERB)saltar), ((VERB)volar) y ((VERB)caminar) para llegar a ese lugar'`

- En este otro caso si hay que dividir la cadena:

`'El árbol ((VERB grande)), las hojas ((VERB)son) doradas y ((VERB)son) secas, los juegos del parque ((VERB)estan) algo oxidados y ((VERB)es) peligroso subirse a ellos'`

, obteniendo así la siguiente cadena como **salida**:

```py
['El árbol ((VERB grande)),' , 
'las hojas ((VERB)son) doradas y ((VERB)son) secas,', 
'los juegos del parque ((VERB)estan) algo oxidados y ((VERB)es) peligroso subirse a ellos']
```

Si aplico este proceso a las 5 cadenas originales en la variable `sentences_list`, **deberia obtener esta lista como output**:

```py
['hay que ((VERB correr)), ((VERB)saltar), ((VERB)volar) y ((VERB)caminar) para llegar a ese lugar',

'El árbol ((VERB grande)),', 
'las hojas ((VERB)son) doradas y ((VERB)son) secas,', 
'los juegos del parque ((VERB)estan) algo oxidados y ((VERB)es) peligroso subirse a ellos',

'El viento es ((VERB)cálido) y ((VERB)es)) rápido y ((VERB)sacude) las hojas de los arboles',

'Hay ((VERB)terminar) esto y eso,', 
'luego hay que ((VERB)limpiar) y ((VERB)llevar) esas cosas y', 
'Tom ((VERB)vendrá) por nosotras',

'María ((VERB)pasará) unos días aqui,',
'hay que ((VERB)mover) sus cosas viejas de aqui,', 
'ya que sus cosméticos ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí.', 

'ya lo hemos ((VERB)estudiado) y ((VERB)analizado),', 
'tom ya se ((VERB)encargo) de lo demás']
```

Algunos elementos de la lista aparecen con espacios entre ellos para mostrar de dónde provienen esas cadenas, pero eso es solo para fines de visualización en la pregunta de stack.

---

**EDIT:**

```
import re

i_input_text = ['hay que ((VERB correr)), ((VERB)saltar), ((VERB)volar) y ((VERB)caminar) para llegar a ese lugar']

aux_list = []
for i_input_text in sentences_list:
    #SEPARATE LISTS HERE
    aux_i_list = []
    
    verb_pattern = r"((VERB)(?:\w+\s*)+)"
    other_words_pattern = r"((?:\w+))?" #patron para palabras que no respondan a verb_pattern
    separator symbols = "(?:,|;|\.|(?:,|)\s*y (?:l[oa]s|la|[eé]l)|(?:,|)\s*y ^[A-Z])'
    
    #patron que usaria un capture group() y esa string que capturo la usaria en el .split()
    string_separator_criteria = 
    
    aux_i_list  = i_input_text.split(string_separator_criteria)

    aux_list.append(i_input_text)

#I update the original variable with the string with the separations already done
sentences_list = aux_list
print(sentences_list) #--> print output list
```

Comment: Hola Mati, deberías aportar tu código si querés obtener ayuda, decinos que falla, que salida tenes, etc.

Comment: @MarcePuente Tienes razon, aunque la verdad es que no habia colocado mi code completo porque no queria que quedase mas larga la pregunta. De todos modos, he actualizado mi pregunta y agregue mi código al final. Lo que estaba pensando hacer es usar un .split() pero como el split no trabaja con regex, entonces se me ocurrió hacer que una regex capture las cadenas separadoras y luego se las envié al split, que sera el encargado de dividir la string

Comment: @MarcePuente Encontré algunos problemas con eso, sobre todo en el como identificar que una string en medio de separadores cuente con 3 o mas palabras (interpretando como "palabra" independiente a una substring que almenos tiene un espacio en medio del resto) ademas de la encapsulación de un verbo, hacer algo como esto `",\s*((?:\w+))?\s*((?:\w+))?\s*((?:\w+))?\s*((VERB)(?:\w+\s*)+)\s*,"`  solo trae el inconveniente que no puedes saber en que posición estara el verbo, quizás esta en medio de la segunda y tercera palabra o quizás esta al final justo antes del separador (en este caso la coma `,`)

Comment: El modulo re tiene un split que funciona con regex: re.split

Comment: @DanteS. Es verdad que aprovechar la función `re.split(re_pattern, input_string)` para separar ocurrencias regex en lugar de string concretas ayuda bastante a simplificar evitando que use un `re.search()` y luego los `.groups()` pasárselos como strings a un `.split()` normal. Pero el problema queda en el orden en el que podría llegar a estar el `((VERB) )` dentro de la substring en medio de los caracteres que uso de separadores.

Comment: La condición es que para realizar la separación debe cumplirse que este `separator_symbols + sentence + separator_symbols` , pero a la vez que `sentence` tenga almenos 3 palabras ademas del verbo en medio de `((VERB) )`

Comment: La frase `'hay que ((VERB correr)), ((VERB)saltar), ((VERB)volar) y ((VERB)caminar) para llegar a ese lugar'` contiene más de tres palabras. ¿Por qué no se divide?

Comment: ¿Dónde usas este patrón `(( VERB)( ?:\w+\s*)+)`? ¿Error de tipeo?

Comment: @CandidMoe No no es error, cada frase que intenta separarse es porque esta en medio de separadores `separator_symbols = r'(?:(?:,|;|\.|)\s*y\s+|,\s*|;\s*)(?:[A-Z]|l[oa]s|la|[eé]l)'`, en ese caso las comas y el inicio y fin de la cadena son los separadores, cheque que todos los `((VERB) )` estan solos, o sea tienen 0 palabras ademas de ellas en las oraciones entre comas. Excepto por hay que `((VERB correr))` que tiene 2 palabras, aunque aun no llega a las 3 palabras por lo que no se le dividió. El unico error de tipeo habia sido el cierre dle parentesis que comente arriba